# Do I need to download javafx12?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I have been having trouble utilizing Javafx within Intellij. I run into the error "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" that I see a lot of other people have.

My main question is do I need to download Javafx12 sdk. I am able to use Dr.Java to run some of my old javafx projects just fine after adding an extra class path and I haven't needed to downloaded anything. It doesn't seem like I need to download anything as another much more basic IDE is able to run javafx. So why does it seem like intellij requires an extra download?

Answer (score 1):

If you moved to Java 12, then yes, you need to download the JavaFX 12 from their new website https://openjfx.io. Luckily installing it is pretty straightforward and well-explained.

It worked before because JavaFX was shipped inside the JDK distribution, which is no longer the case. Swing however is still there and will work as before. (I am not saying you go back to Swing, just that it is still shipped along the JDK)